# Handle Pagination Sorting and Filtering Separately in Antd Table React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I want to handle server-side sorting, filtering, and pagination separately in my antd table. So whenever pagination is changed it should not call the sorting and filtering function. similarly for both for sorting and filtering. In the antd documentation for Table, they have used onChange prop which will be called whenever sorting, filtering or pagination is changed. https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-ajax

To handle pagination alone I've used Pagination's onChange prop. But here when pagination is changed it's calling sorting and filtering function and also when sorting and filtering is changed it calls the pagination function.

I'm not sure how to achieve this functionality. Can anyone please help me with this.

Example antd code for the table

```
const handlePagination = page => {
    //This should be called only when pagination changes
    dispatch(PaginateData(page));
};

const handleSortFilter= params=> {
    //This should be called only when pagination or sorting is called.
    dispatch(SortFilterData(params));
};

<Table
    rowSelection={rowSelection}
    onChange={handleSortFilter}
    rowKey={record => record.id}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    loading={tableActionInProgress}
    pagination={{
        onChange: handlePagination,
        pageSize: dataPerPage,
        total: CountData
    }}
/>
```

**Update**
In the the antd table documentation for ajax requests (https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-ajax) I could see that whenever we change sort or filter it changes the page back to 1. Is there anything I need to change in the code so that whenever filter or sorting is changed it should not set the page parameter to 1.

Why I need to perform this is because when the user changes the filter or sorting in a specific page it should not take him back to the first page instead if I get in which page (page number) the user tried to filter or sort, so that I can send the page number in the request and filter/sort accordingly to the page in the backend and send the response back. Is there any option not to set the page back to 1 if sorting or filtering is applied on the antd table.

Comment: Please try making a producible example so we could edit it, you can use a sandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96, you can refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks for your reply, I've added the example code which is there in antd documentation (https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-ajax). You can find the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-khorana-qkpwp

Comment: @DennisVash So basically my problem is whenever sorting or filtering is applied to the antd table then the page is set 1. Is it the default behavior of antd? Can we customize it in such a way that even if I'm on a specific page and apply the sorting/filtering it should not set the page back to 1, rather it should send the request with the page number we're on and filter/sort parameters.

Comment: I got you, it's not the default behaviour, in the codebox you shared, on every sort the data **is changing**, what do you expect to happen on when the data changed? To remain on the same page altought you don't know what happened on the first page? It is not a desirable behavior.

Comment: The `Table` will "reset" itself to page 1 **only when it loses its state**. Without seeing any code, or a **producible example** I can't guess how you implementing your sorting and how you handle the rendering on fetching. You have enough free resources for making a mocking fetch example and sharing it for making your question a complete one.

Comment: @DennisVash actually I'm working on a project where backend API is already there which will take page number and filter/sort parameters. (sharing backend API is difficult in the codesandbox so I just put the antd's ajax example ).So in my project whenever antd table's sort or filter changes, it actually set's the paginator's current page to 1 even if we're on a specific page. Consider I'm on a page 3, and in the page 3 if press sort option for a specific column it should not set the paginator.current to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200451/discussion-between-aashay-amballi-and-dennis-vash).

Answer (score 17):

For manage filters, sort and pagination in backend you need to use [api parameter](https://ant.design/components/table/#API) of table `onChange`:

```
<Table
    columns={[
      //...
    ]}
    rowKey="key"
    dataSource={youSource}
    onChange={handleChange}
    pagination={{
       total: totalCount // total count returned from backend
    }}
/>
```

Our `handleChange`:

```
const handleChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
  const offset = pagination.current * pagination.pageSize - pagination.pageSize;
  const limit = pagination.pageSize;
  const params = {};

  if (sorter.hasOwnProperty("column")) {
    params.order = { field: sorter.field, dir: sorter.order };
  }

  getData(offset, limit, params);
};
```

Getting data from API:

```
const getData = (offset, limit, params = false) => {

  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();

  queryParams.append("offset", offset);
  queryParams.append("limit", limit);
  queryParams.append("offset", offset);

  if(params && params.order) {
    queryParams.append("order", JSON.stringify(params.order));
  }

  // In this example I use axios to fetch
  axios
    .get(`https://example.com/you/endpoint/?${queryParams.toString()}`)
    .then((response) => {
      // get response
      console.log("Response: ", response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

You already decide how fetch data, or if you have possibility to implement backend logic, implement query with params from GET.